# Python Scrapy - how to tick checkboxes and search before scraping specific data

Tags: python, scrapy

I got this site https://www.ingenieurs-ensea.fr/annuaire/recherche

I need to tick 2023, 2022, 2021 boxes then follow with search button which has input submit type.

On page that follows I got a list of 700+ names and descriptions in 30+ pages that I need to have as 3 seperate tables in Excel (eg. name + rank and year from description in seperate columns)

I tried a various stiched attempts but didn't work.

This was my last attempt but I'm kinda lost overall.

```
class Names(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'enseafr'
    settings = get_project_settings()
    start_urls = ['https://www.ingenieurs-ensea.fr/annuaire/recherche',]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'DiplomePromo[]':'2023'},
        formname='DiplomePromo1',
        callback= self.parse_2,
        method= "POST",
    )

    def parse_2(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'DiplomePromo[]': '2022'},
        formname='DiplomePromo2',
        callback=self.parse_3,
        method="POST",
    )

    def parse_3(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'DiplomePromo[]': '2021'},
        formname='DiplomePromo3',
        callback=self.after_parse,
        method="POST",
    )

    def after_parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata= {'': 'RECHERCHER'},
        callback = self.data,
        method = "POST",
    )

    def data(self, response):
        items = IngItems()
        for item in response.xpath('//div[@class="annuaire_result_list"'):
            items['name'] = item.xpath('//*[@id="zoneAnnuaire_layout"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/text()').get()
            items['description'] = item.xpath('//*[@id="zoneAnnuaire_layout"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]').get()
        yield items
```

It just produces bunch of errors so I guess its super broken

Comment: Use Selenium Webdriver to interact with web elements

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this link instead. I got it from the Network tab:

```
https://www.ingenieurs-ensea.fr/annuaire/recherche?result=1&annuaire_mode=standard&annuaire_as_no=&keyword=&PersonneNom=&PersonnePrenom=&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2023&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2022&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2021
```

Comment: Hey I used that link and I think I got banned on that site. Set up user_agents and proxies and testing to scrape just 1 page for names and details but I get no output could You check it out? https://paste.tortoisecommunity.com/peyilifibo.py